# Remove Duplicate Columns Records and Keep One for Respective Row

Tags: sql, zoho

```
SELECT
         Min("Id") as 'Id',
         Min("Created Time") as 'Created Time',
         Min("Adjusted Amount") as 'Adjusted Amount',
         "Collection Date",
         Min("Collection Mode") as 'Collection Mode',
         Min("Collection Status") as 'Collection Status',
         Min("Invoice No.") as 'Invoice No.',
         Min("Note") as 'Note',
         "Opportunity-ID",
         sum("Collection Amount") AS 'Collection Amount',
         sum("Rep eligible Collection value") AS 'Rep Eligible Collection Value',
FROM  "Payment Collection Info" 
GROUP BY "Opportunity-ID",
      "Collection Date"
```

In the above code for the "Opportunity-ID" column have duplicates but I want to keep unique records. If the "Opportunity-ID" found more than once then we need to keep that "Opportunity-ID" once for the respective row and we will remove the remaining duplicate "Opportunity-ID"s.

I tried with subquery but it didn't helped its showing I have to use ANY OR IN. I search through different stack overflow threads I didn't find a relevant answer.

Comment: This is from site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Got it next time onwards I will make sure of it.

Comment: Update this question, or you risk your post being downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT
      "Opportunity-ID"
    , "Collection Date" 
FROM  "Payment Collection Info" 
GROUP BY
      "Opportunity-ID"
    , "Collection Date"
```

Will produce the exact same list as this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      "Opportunity-ID"
    , "Collection Date" 
FROM  "Payment Collection Info"
```

In other words BOTH of those query CANNOT produce "duplicates" because **each row** is a **unique combination** of values.

However, "Opportunity-ID" **can** be repeated, but only if there are several different "Collection Date"s.  So, if you want to only output only one row for each "Opportunity-ID" **you** have to decide which "Collection Date" to keep. e.g. do you only keep the most recent collection date? or the first(oldest) collection date? E.G:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
          "Id"
        , "Created Time"
        , "Adjusted Amount"
        , "Collection Date"
        , "Collection Mode"
        , "Collection Status"
        , "Invoice No."
        , "Note"
        , "Opportunity-ID"
        , "Collection Amount"
        , "Rep eligible Collection value"
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Opportunity-ID"
                            ORDER BY "Collection Date" ASC) AS OLDEST
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Opportunity-ID"
                            ORDER BY "Collection Date" DESC) AS NEWEST
    FROM "Payment Collection Info"
    ) AS D
WHERE OLDEST = 1
-- WHERE NEWEST = 1
```

Note also, that IF you choose to deliberately omit rows then the SUMs may now be wrong or unexpected.